# Add active class for both div bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have such html

```
 <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      {% for project in similarProjects %}
        <div class="item {% if loop.first %}active{% endif %}">
           <span >{{ project.title }}</span>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>

   <article>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
         {% for project in similarProjects %}
            <div class="item {% if loop.first %}active{% endif %}">
              {{ project.text }}
            </div>
         {% endfor %}
      </div>
   </article>
```

I need to when i click on my navigation, turning the pages and page titles and text. Now if I click, for example, scroll to the right, just flipping the text and title remains the same. Please, help me solve this problem.

P.S.
My nav

```
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
```

Right side the same

Comment: use `:focus` or `:active` pseudo class to achieve that

Comment: @Amitsingh your  answer doesn't correct

Comment: Add a working Fiddle, your question is incomplete